# How to make 2 server threads communicate with 2 client threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, inputstream, outputstream

I basically want to achieve this:

```
ServerThreadA                         ClientThreadA
             \                       /
               --->>>--->>>--->>>---
                      SOCKET
               --->>>--->>>--->>>---
             /                       \
ServerThreadB                         ClientThreadB
```

What's happening here is that I have 2 threads on the server sending data to 2 respective threads on the client side. To be more specific I'd need to use .writeUTF(String) from DataOutputStream on the server and .readUTF() from DataInputStream on the client.

When ServerThreadA writes something to the stream only ClientThreadA shall read it, and not ClientThreadB. In the same way I don't want ClientThreadB to read what ServerThreadA has written.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

EDIT:
I think I might have explained poorly: I already know how to make a server that can accept multiple connections and give each one of them a thread to work on, what I'm trying to is to have multiple communications going on in the same direction and in the same client. So let's say the server connects to a client, a thread is created representing the connection but what I want to do is read from 2 different channels, if you will, transfering different types of data. For example I might want the client to send two strings simultaneously and the server to read them *at the same time*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change protocol so that before each String a number should be written: 0 if the message is for ClientThreadA, and 1 if message is for ClientThreadB.

At the server side, start a ClientThread0 which should read all the input data from the socket. It reads a number and then a string in a loop. Then passes the string to appropriate thread depending on the number. To pass messages from the ClientThread0  to ClientThreadA/B, `BlockingQueue<String>`s are used. ClientThread0 calls to `queue.put(string)`, and ClientThreadA/B call to `queue.take()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **ServerSocket** for server where the sever accepts the **port number** which are passed or called by the client.

Both use the same **port number** for communicating.

Many number of clients can call the server. As the client request (on that port number) server accepts client request it means client joins to the server....

Comment: I think I might have explained poorly: I already know how to make a server that can accept multiple connections and give each one of them a thread to work on, what I'm trying to is to have multiple communications going on in the same direction and in the same client. So let's say the server connects to a client, a thread is created representing the connection but what I want to do is read from 2 different channels, if you will, transfering different types of data. For example I might want the client to send two strings simultaneously and the server to read them *at the same time*

Comment: you mean two different client send the two different data to single server and server accepts both the data at the same time..

Comment: No, each client sends two different data to the server. The problem is that it has to happen simultaneously using multithreading

Comment: Ok then make two different client with two different name and call through the thread.

Answer (score 0):

I think your understanding of how servers should work is wrong. That picture should very much look like:

```
ServerThreadA --->>>--->>>--->>>--- ClientThreadA

ServerThreadB --->>>--->>>--->>>--- ClientThreadB
```

The point is: the server code waits on **one** server socket; and when a new client comes in and [accept()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept()) gives you a "dedicated" socket to talk to that client.

In other words: no matter how many client threads connect to your server; and no matter how many server threads take care with them; there is always **one** specific socket **per** client.

There is no sharing of sockets; thus there is no need to worry about messages that could go to more than one client!

And when you thought about "sharing" sockets to allow one side to send messages to *all* peers on the other side, then you need to do using different ways!

Comment: I think I might have explained poorly: I already know how to make a server that can accept multiple connections and give each one of them a thread to work on, what I'm trying to is to have multiple communications going on in the same direction and in the same client. So let's say the server connects to a client, a thread is created representing the connection but what I want to do is read from 2 different channels, if you will, transfering different types of data. For example I might want the client to send two strings simultaneously and the server to read them *at the same time*